# How to solve 8 unknowns and 12 linear equations OVER DETERMINED system?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

How to solve for a system of 8 unknowns and 12 linear equations?
I use MATLAB, but answers change based on the choice of equations set. Is there any way can I solve and get consistent answer using all 12 equations for 8 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

This is something like passing a line from 3 points. If they are all aligned, yes you can find a line passing all of them. But if not then you should choose which line best fits your situation.

1) You may say, my line must strictly pass the first 2 points, then you drop the 3rd point from your equation set.

2) You can say I should obtain a line which is close to the 3 points as much as possible. Then you define "being close as much as possible" as minimizing your error term. A well known method of minimizing error term is least square error. And in order to obtain a "least-square error" based solution of an over-determined system you should create "Normal Equation System" which is a square system, then solve it.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if there non-linear equation set for the same case of 8 independent variables and 12 equations,  how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Let the $12\times8$ matrix be $A$, and the length-12 column vector $b$, so your equation is $Ax=b$.
As you note, it is overdetermined, so it is unlikely to have a single solution.
The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is sometimes used, if $A$ is full rank:
$$x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if there non-linear equation set for the same case of 8 independent variables and 12 equations,  how would I proceed?